# Team City 8 - Specification for external SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, teamcity-8.0

We have Team City server with Team City 8.1 installed and are currently using the internal DB option but as recommended we want to move to an external DB.

We have the following configuration on the server (everything is on the one virtual server Quad core and 4GBytes)

1. We have 5 active projects with 57 build configurations. Have a maximum of 60 build configurations. So 6 active build agents
2. We run all the configs with MSTest/C#
3. We plan to maybe go to maybe 10 build agents

We are being asked by our DB team what size we need and they want a specific specification for the SQL Server database for this team city database ie number of cores, log space etc etc..

Anybody know what the specification should be roughly so I can guide our DB Ops team????

Comment: You should probably ask that question the jetbrains sales or support team.